# PHP built in server using insane amounts of memory

Tags: php, symfony

So when I start PHP's built in server with command:

```
php app/console server:run
```

The php process that gets spawned, initially uses about 20MB memory, and it just keeps increasing automatically, even if I don't actually use it (as in browse the actual app on the browser. It goes up to 1GB memory usage, and then only reason it stops, is because i kill it.

This same does not happen if I start server in some other directory, directly with PHPs command `php -S localhost:8080`

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using anything like `fingers crossed` logging ?

Comment: I have no idea what `fingers crossed` logging is, but I came here to say that I 'fixed' the issue, by using `php app/console server:start` instead. I have no idea what the difference is, but it returned control to terminal immediately, ant it started of at 15MB usage, and it seems to be staying there.

Answer (score 0):

Some systems do not support the server:start command, in these cases you can execute the server:run command. This command behaves slightly different. Instead of starting the server in the background, it will block the current terminal until you terminate it (this is usually done by pressing Ctrl and C).

Comment: Yeah but is it expected behaviour that 'server:run` will use like 1GB of memory?

Comment: Yeah it can, as it blocks the current terminal which results in blocking of resources and blocking resources for any process shows the processed as used.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I used phps server `php -S ...`, which blocks the terminal, and I certainly did not have that problem.